# STS Custom Template

Tags: java, json, spring, templates, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm having an issue in STS creating a custom template. What I want is the ability to do token-based replacement within all files in the project. I've read this is possible with the "token" replacement, but cannot seem to get the wizard.json to let me accept multiple inputs. The "example" you see everywhere is replacing the top-level-package, which I've got to work great.

Anyone have any examples of doing multiple inputs in the wizard.json, or have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is what I have, which doesn't work:

```
{
"info" : {
    "elements" : {
        "element" : [
            {
                "name" : "mysystem",
                "description" : "Please the name of your system (ex. marketing, hr, accounting, etc).",
                "type" : "java.lang.String",
                "page" : 0,
                "required" : true,
                "pattern" : "\\w+",
                "replaceKind" : "token"
            }
        ],
        "element" : [
            {
                "name" : "myapp",
                "description" : "Please the name of your application (ex. thisapplication, thatapplication, etc).",
                "type" : "java.lang.String",
                "page" : 0,
                "required" : true,
                "pattern" : "\\w+",
                "replaceKind" : "token"
            }
        ]
    },

    "projectName" : "projectName",

    "pages" : {
        "page" : [
                {
                "order" : 0,
                "description" : "System Info"
                }
          ]
    }
}
}
```

The "myapp" picks up and does the translation, but the "mysystem" never even gets displayed for input (screen one is just the myapp text).

Comment: What "example" did you follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who run into the same problem, I have figured this out. Here is what I ended up with.

```
{
"info" : {
    "elements" : {
        "element" : [
            {
                "name" : "mysystem",
                "description" : "Please the name of your system (ex. marketing, hr, accounting, etc).",
                "type" : "java.lang.String",
                "page" : 0,
                "required" : true,
                "pattern" : "\\w+",
                "replaceKind" : "token"
            },
            {
                "name" : "myapp",
                "description" : "Please the name of your application (ex. thisapplication, thatapplication, etc).",
                "type" : "java.lang.String",
                "page" : 1,
                "required" : true,
                "pattern" : "\\w+",
                "replaceKind" : "token"
            }
        ]
    },

    "projectName" : "projectName",

    "pages" : {
        "page" : [
                {
                "order" : 0,
                "description" : "System Info"
                }
          ],
          "page" : [
                {
                "order" : 1,
                "description" : "System Info 2"
                }
          ]
    }
}
```

}